# MVC ActionLink parameter "doesn't exists in current context"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem with JavaScript code.

```
$.getJSON("/Home/GetJson", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            'position': new google.maps.LatLng(
                            item.CoordinatesPlace.Latitude, 
                            item.CoordinatesPlace.Longitude
            ),
            'map': map,
            'title': item.Name
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:'@Html.ActionLink("Details","Details",new { id= item.Id})'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    })
});
```

In `'@Html.ActionLink("Details","Details",new { id= item.Id})'` I get *"item doesn't exist in current context"*.

How can I pass the `item.Id` to `@Html.ActionLink`?

Comment: That does not look like JavaScript. What kind of markup is this? Is it processed serverside? Then you cannot use it like this anyway.

Comment: I think you should add "C#" and "ASP.NET MVC" tags, since it's not pure javascript

Comment: What kind of tags i should add?It's a part of MVC project

Answer (score 1):

```
content:'@Html.ActionLink("Details","Details",new { id= '+item.Id+'})'
```

I believe you got the change I have made here. To append the actual value of id to the string, we are using the '+' symbols here.

Comment: { id= '+item.Id+'} gives me an error "Too many characters in literal" :/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use javascript variables in razor because the razor view is parsed in the server and javascript runs in the client. You can however use razor to generate the url except the parameters, that you can then add in javascript:

```
content: '@Url.Action("Details", "Details")' + '?' + $.param({id: item.Id})
```

I used *$.param* here because if you want to add several parameters it will handle putting the '&' between them for you, i.e. `$.param({id:1, otherParam:2}) -> id=1&otherParam=2`

Comment: Thank you so much!But how i could create a link from @Url.Action("Details", "Details")' + '?' + $.param({id: item.Id})?

Comment: @myID33 I don't know if I understand what you mean... Url.Action will return a url, for example `http://localhost/Details/Details` that wil then be concatenated with ?id=1 which will result in a valid url: `http://localhost/Details/Details?id=1`. If you put in in an anchor tag (`<a href="http://...">Click me</a>`) it will cause the Details's controler action detail to be invoked with id=1 when you click it.

Comment: I mean the same,but <a href="@Url.Action("details","details")' + '?' + $.param({ id: item.Id }">Know more</a> is not the correct form

Comment: @myID33 store the url in javascript variable and then set the anchor tag's href with jquery, here's a very [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/6hKFx/). The reason for your suggestion not working is that the href does not expect a javascript expression.